# Wordpress css file not updating

Tags: wordpress, caching

I am having a serious issue with my stylesheet. Here is whats going on:

1. I have a version for my stylesheet
2. In the theme editor the file is correct
3. Nothing gets updated when I view the file in my browser even after purging cache from wpengine and my browser history

What is going on? This is driving me mad.

Comment: Do you have a URL you can add to review? If you inspect in your browser, are you seeing your previous style sheet and not the updated one?

Comment: you are using any cache plugin or check cpanel cache

Comment: you can check the version of the css file via viewing the source of the web page (and checking its head), or via (in Chrome -- though other browsers probably have similar features) more tools -> developer tools --> sources tab.

Comment: Hit the css file url in the browser, and check, whether it's now updated or not, if not then you probably editing a wrong file or you are seeing a wrong file, if it's updated then refresh your web page and the changes will be reflected. For better results, make these things done in the incognito windows.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone who answered this. My client unfortunately did not tell me they had cloudflare adding additional cache, which was the issue.